# Does drierite produce particles when drying and filtering compressed air?

Tags: compressed-air, air, drying, air-filtration

I need to dry and filter some air for an air-driven rotary tool. I have an in-line drierite container but wonder if it will itself produce particles.  Because of the fittings I have available it would be “convenient” to use it after a 5 micron filter, but if this is going to produce particles it seems like a “bad idea”.

I will also have a 3 micron filter after the drierite (followed by an oiler and then the tool).

The order would be:

[compressor input filter][compressor][5um filter][drierite][3um filter][oiler][high speed air tool]

[image]